# Unable to use both role and authorities at same time while creating a new user, using Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using the following code to create an in-memory user:

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
    manager.createUser(User.withUsername("user").password("pass").authorities("READ","WRITE").roles("USER").build());
    System.out.println("user created");
    return manager;
}
```

I have the following code in one of my REST Controller methods:

```
System.out.println("printing authorities..");
User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    user.getAuthorities().forEach(item-> System.out.println(item.toString()));
```

I get the following output:

```
printing authorities..
ROLE_USER
```

My question, is this supposed to be so? If a do a chained method call `authorities("XX").roles("YY")`, the later over writes the former.

I want to use a Custom `PermissionEvaluator` to evaluate permission, on top of a check for the role. How can I provide additional permissions like read/write to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question, is this supposed to be so? If a do a chained method call
>   authorities("XX").roles("YY"), the later over writes the former.

As @dur mentioned, this is the way it is implemented. But be aware that
`hasRole('XX')` will check for **Role_XX** in your app, whereas
`hasAuthroirty('XX')` will check for **XX**. Depends on, how your application is defining the roles. If every role is prefixed with **Role_** in your app, hasRole provides a convenient way to auto append that prefix.

> I want to use a Custom PermissionEvaluator to evaluate permission, on
>   top of a check for the role. How can I provide additional permissions
>   like read/write to the user?

I guess you have already put that in your code with this line:

```
.authorities("READ","WRITE")
```

Since this `.roles("USER")` is overriding the previous declaration, you can change it to:

```
.authorities("READ","WRITE","ROLE_USER")
```

and remove the `roles` declaration.